# Grunt & requirejs optimizer for a multi app project

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, task, gruntjs

I'm having issues getting Grunt to perform requirejs optimization on a project with the following structure:

```
static/js
    |── apps
        |── app.js
        |── dash.js
        |── news.js
        ... (many more 'app' files)
    |── build
    |── collections
    |── libs
    |── models
    |── util
    |── views
```

Each of `static/js/apps/*.js` should be compiled to `static/js/build/*.js` containing the relevant dependencies (eg. `views/view1`, `libs/query` etc).

This is currently being performed by a basic bash script:

```
JS_ROOT="static/js"

for f in ${JS_ROOT}/apps/*
do
    FILE=$(basename -s .js ${f})
    pushd .
    cd ${JS_ROOT} && r.js -o baseUrl=. name=libs/require-min.js include=apps/${FILE} out=build/${FILE}.js
    popd
done
```

I'm attempting to move to a Grunt-based optimization, with the following in `Grunt.js`:

```
requirejs: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            appDir: 'static/js/',
            baseUrl: './apps/',
            dir: 'static/js/build/',
            modules: [
                {
                    name: 'app',
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Running generates the following error:

```
>> Tracing dependencies for: app
>> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>> 'static/js/build/apps/libs/jquery.js'
>> In module tree:
>>     app
```

I can clearly see what the problem is, but am failing to figure out how to indicate that the dependencies in each `static/js/apps/*.js` file are in `static/js/` not `static/js/build`

In addition to this, I'm assuming that the `modules` block containing `name: 'app'` should be outputting the compiled file `static/js/build/app.js` from the contents of `static/js/apps/app.js`.

Without creating an additional `module` block for each file in `static/js/apps`, how can I compile each of the files into their relevant `static/js/build/*.js` file?

**Update 1**

So the following in my Gruntfile compiles `static/js/apps/app.js` successfully into `static/js/build/app.js`:

```
requirejs: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: 'static/js/',
            include: './apps/app.js',
            out: 'static/js/build/app.js',
        }
    }
}
```

The next step being to compile `static/js/apps/*.js` into `static/js/build/*.js` without having to define each individually...

**Update 2**

Modifying the above to:

```
requirejs: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: '../',
            include: './apps/<%= appFile %>',
            out: 'static/js/build/<%= appFile %>',
        }
    }
}
```

And creating the task:

```
grunt.registerTask('buildrjs', function() {
    var dir='static/js/apps/';
    grunt.file.setBase(dir);
    var files = grunt.file.expand(['*.js']);
    files.forEach(function(filename) {
        grunt.log.write('Compiling '+filename+'\n');
        grunt.config.set('appFile', filename);
        grunt.task.run('requirejs:compile');
    });
});
```

Almost gets me to the solution. The tasks runs through each file in `static/js/apps/` and passes the filename into `grunt.config.set('appFile', filename);`. The output of the task outputs `Compiling app.js Compiling news.js...` etc, however afterwards the actual `requirejs:compile` tasks runs over & over on the last file in the `static/js/apps/` directory, rather than each individual file. An async issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved, by passing multiple sets of options to the requirejs task, thanks to [this article](http://clintconklin.com/optimizing-multiple-javascript-files-with-grunt-and-requirejs/) for the final pointers I needed:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var files = grunt.file.expand('static/js/apps/*.js');
    var requirejsOptions = {};

    files.forEach(function(file) {
        var filename = file.split('/').pop();
        requirejsOptions[filename] = {
            options: {
                baseUrl: 'static/js/',
                include: './apps/'+filename,
                out: 'static/js/build/'+filename
            }
        };
    });

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        requirejs: requirejsOptions,
    });
};
```

Then the `['requirejs']` task can be run as normal and will output the appropriate compiled .js file as per each of the `options: {}` blocks that were specified in `requirejsOptions`, eg:

`grunt.registerTask('default', ['requirejs']);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change baseUrl to **static/js** from **apps** in requirejs build config. As currently baseUrl is pointing to **apps** directory, require is trying to search dependency files in apps directory. If you change the baseUrl to **static/js** it will find those dependency files.

```
   requirejs: {
     compile: {
       options: {
         appDir: 'static/js/',
         baseUrl: 'static/js',
         dir: 'static/js/build/',
         modules: [
          {
                name: 'app',
          }
         ]
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: But `baseUrl` is relative to `appDir`, so when loading the `app` module requirejs will be looking in `/static/js/static/js/app.js`.

Comment: Sorry I missed that point. Then you can change BaseUrl to __.__ baseUrl: "."

Comment: Thanks. In this case however, the `module` would need updating to `name: 'apps/app'`. This results in the entire contents of `static/js` being copied into `static/js/build`.