# grunt requirejs compile multi-mainConfigFile

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I have issues with compile multi-mainConfigFile in grunt-contrib-requirejs.

I don't know how to configure the gruntfile.js，although read page '[Grunt & requirejs optimizer for a multi app project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583812/grunt-requirejs-optimizer-for-a-multi-app-project)'.

- I have thesee files

`.
├── index.js
├── main.js
└── module
    ├── common.js
    └── dao.js`

- requirejs config in gruntfile.js

```
 requirejs: {

```
compile: {

   options: {

     name : "main",
                optimize: "uglify",
                mainConfigFile: "./assets/js/main.js",
                out: "./static/js/app.min.js"
            }
        }
    }
```

```

That is all .

I want to compile index.js and main.js .

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the article you read is saying make another sibling block to compile with the other configuration.

e.g.

```
requirejs: {
  main: {
    options: {
      // first config
    }
  },
  index: {
    options: {
      // second config
    }
  }
}
```

On a side note, if you want shared dependencies across the two apps and one config file, there's a concept called requirejs modules.